# I'm writing a letter counter and was wondering how to make the dictionary show up once at the bottom (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I was writing a letter counter function and wanted the result to be returned like this:
letter_counter('Python'):

```
The letter h is in the string python 1 time(s).
The letter n is in the string python 1 time(s).
The letter o is in the string python 1 time(s).
The letter p is in the string python 1 time(s).
The letter t is in the string python 1 time(s).
The letter y is in the string python 1 time(s).
{'h': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 1, 't': 1, 'y': 1}
```

However I get this:

```
The letter h is in the string python 1 time(s).
{'h': 1}
The letter n is in the string python 1 time(s).
{'n': 1}
The letter o is in the string python 1 time(s).
{'o': 1}
The letter p is in the string python 1 time(s).
{'p': 1}
The letter t is in the string python 1 time(s).
{'t': 1}
The letter y is in the string python 1 time(s).
{'y': 1}
```

Here's what i've done so far:

```
maximum = 26
def letter_counter(string) : 
    dic = {}
    n = len(string)
    f = [ 0 ] * maximum  
  
    for i in range(n) : 
        f[ord(string[i]) - ord('a')] += 1  
  
    for i in range(maximum) :  
        if (f[i] == 0) : 
            continue
        dic[(chr)(i + ord('a'))] = f[i]
        ch = (chr)(i + ord('a'))
        # print the result alphabetically
        print("The letter",ch,"is in the string",string,f[i], "time(s).")
        print(dic)
    return dic
```

Comment: Indentations is incorrect. print(dic)

Comment: Not true, that output isn't what that code produces.

Comment: Sorry, i edited it again

Comment: Out-dent the next to last line `print(dic)` one level.  You don't want it within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Indentations, Indentations print(dic).

Your code produces correct output.

```
   for i in range(maximum):
    if (f[i] == 0):
        continue
    dic[(chr)(i + ord('a'))] = f[i]
    ch = (chr)(i + ord('a'))

    print("The letter", ch, "is in the string", string, f[i], "time(s).")
print(dic)
return dic
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  Out-dent the next to last line print(dic) one level. You don't want it within the loop. and you are in business.

```
def letter_counter(string):
    dic = {}
    n = len(string)
    f = [0] * maximum

    for i in range(n):
        f[ord(string[i]) - ord('a')] += 1

    for i in range(maximum):
        if (f[i] == 0):
            continue
        dic[(chr)(i + ord('a'))] = f[i]
        ch = (chr)(i + ord('a'))
        # print the result alphabetically
        print("The letter", ch, "is in the string", string, f[i], "time(s).")
    print(dic)
    return dic
```

Here is a more concise version if you are interested:

```
def letter_counter2(string):
    dic = {}
    [dic.update({c: string.count(c)}) for c in string]
    return dic

print(letter_counter2('asdfasdfasdfffddds'))
```

Let's walk through some of this form the inside out.

- `string.count(c)` returns a count of the occurrences of c in string.
- `{c: string.count(c)}` creates a single entry dictionary object.
- `dic.update({c:string.count(c)})` appends or updates dic[c] with string.count(c).
- `[dic.update({c:string.count(c)}) for c in string]` is a list comprehension, which is like a for loop for sequences (strings, lists, tuples, etc.).  The list comprehension, loops through every character in string and performs the action text between '[' and 'for'.

References:

- str.count(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods
- List comprehension: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions
- Dictionaries: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries